# C# Keep Method Executing/Listening to Data without the use of a While(true) loop or Thread.Sleep?

Tags: c#

I have been given a snippet of data in documentation I was given to receive data from a device.

The code below will only listen for 5 seconds and then the method would return and the program would terminate.

```
public void ListenForData()
{
  ...
  DataReader r = new DataReader();
  ...

  r.DataRead += delegate (Object sender, DataEventArgs e)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Read: " + e.Data);
  };

  r.StartListening();

  Thread.Sleep(5000);

  r.Dispose();
}
```

I want to keep the method open (so I can continue listening to data) but I'm unsure on the proper way to do this. I've looked at responses like:

```
while(true)
{
    //my code
    Thread.sleep(0);
}
```

But I'm not sure that this is the optimal use case. I feel it would hog a lot of CPU and wasn't the true intended way to listen for that data.

So what other options do I have?

Comment: Have a look into asynchronous programming, the `Task` class, and the `async/await` keywords. They're designed specifically to solve this issue. Also, could you clarify if you're able to modify the method which is blocking, or do you have to work with a third party library that you can't change?

Comment: What kind of app are you writing? A console app? WPF? Something else?

Comment: @TamBui A console app

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson It's a third party library assembly

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson Also where would I put the async/await keywords in my code above? I read about Tasked Base Programming in .NET but don't know how to integrate it specifically here

Comment: Actually I think Mr.TA's answer is a better approach here. If you wanted this to use async and await, you could create a [Channel<DataEventArgs>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel?view=netcore-3.1), in your event handler call `channel.Writer.TryWrite(args)`, and then to read you'd call `await channel.Reader.ReadAsync()`. There are a few different ways to achieve the same thing here, but I think the posted answer is the most clear and understandable solution

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a `while` loop containing a `Sleep()` call, though I'd put an actual small value in there...like `Sleep(100)`; it will not hog your CPU cycles then.  Some times it is desirable to have a loop like this since you can then do something periodically, or implement a time-out, etc...

Comment: @Idle_Mind Seems inefficient though. But I guess await and TAP models use it in their backend

Answer (score 2):

I think your `DataReader` needs to be a field somewhere scoped to the duration of you needing to receive data. Something like this (assuming Windows application):

```
class MainForm : Form
{
  DataReader dataReader;
  void listenButton_Click(object s, EventArgs e)
  {
    this.dataReader = new DataReader();
    this.dataReader.DataRead += delegate (Object sender, DataEventArgs e)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Read: " + e.Data);
      };

    this.dataReader.StartListening();
  }
  void stopButton_Click(object s, EventArgs e)
  {
    this.dataReader.Dispose();
    this.dataReader = null;
  }
}
```

Or console:

```
static class Program
{
  static DataReader dataReader;
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    StartListen();
    Console.WriteLine("Push enter to exit");
    Console.ReadLine(); // wait for enter key to exit
    StopListen();
  }
  static void StartListen()
  {
    dataReader = new DataReader();
    dataReader.DataRead += delegate (Object sender, DataEventArgs e)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Read: " + e.Data);
      };

    dataReader.StartListening();
  }
  static void StopListen()
  {
    dataReader.Dispose();
    dataReader = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am using a Console application but I see what you're accomplishing here

I like how you disposed the reader which is good so I can look at using this